# Equilateral triangle in hyperbolic plane

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Show that there is an equilateral triangle with angles $\pi/m$ for any integer $m\ge4$. What is the corresponding result for regular n gon?
My attempt: I know that area of triangle in hyperbolic plane is $\pi-(sum \ of \ angles\  of\  triangles)$ .
Let y axis be my first line choose second line to be a semicircle with centre right of origin such that it makes an angle $\pi/m$ with y axis .Choose third line to be semicircle with centre on left of origin with angle $\pi/m$ with y axis and the area of triangle by the three lines is $3\pi/m$.

1.Why should the third line intersect second line?
2.How do i write this proof rigourously?
I have very little knowledge in this subject so i would prefer an elementary answer.

Comment: Which model of hyperbolic geometry do you use? Using the origin works in the Poincaré disk model but semi circles belong to the Poincare halfplane model don't mix them up

Comment: I am using upper half plane model

Comment: by right of origin i mean the semi circle has centre on +ve x axis

Comment: Not sure if your method will work at all maybe better just calculate the side lengths  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle general trigonometry    start with the point (0,1) then you can calculate the second point on the y axis and so on

Answer (score 1):

> What is the corresponding result for regular $n$ gon?

A regular $n$-gon is highly symmetric. If you draw all the axes of reflective symmetry, the portion between two such axes is a right-angled triangle. One of its corners is at the center, with an interior angle of $\pi/n$ (because $2n$ of these form the full circle), another is at a vertex of the $n$-gon, with the interior angle being half that of the $n$-gon. The third corner is a right angle at the center of an edge of the $n$-gon.

So if you want interior angles of $\pi/m$ at the corners of a regular $n$-gon, you want to know whether there exists a hyperbolic triangle with angles $\frac\pi{n}, \frac\pi{2m}, \frac\pi2$. The sum of these angles being less than $\pi$ is both necessary and sufficient for the existence of such a triangle.

You can then continue by computing the edge lengths of such a triangle, and then constructing the $n$-gon from that.

Answer (score 0):

for an equilateral triangle with angle $\alpha $ and side $s$  the following relations hold ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle#Trigonometry_of_right_triangles aand a bit of puzzeling)

$$\cos \alpha = \frac {\tanh \frac12 s } {\tanh s } $$
and
$$ \cosh\frac12 s = \frac {\cos \frac12 \alpha } {\sin \alpha } $$

then with this knowledge you have enough to construct  equilateral triangle

for the poincare halfplane

for example point $A = (0,1)$ and $B = \ln(s)$ and then construct the lines under angle $ \alpha$ through $A$ and $B$

good luck